# hierarchical clustering for collection of sets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

I have a collection of sets like

```
 b1={a1,a2,a3,a4,a5}
 b2={a6,a7,a8,a9}
 b3={a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10}
 b4={a6,a7,a8,a12}
 b5={a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12}
 c1={d1,d2,d3}     
 c2={d1,d2,d3,d4}
 c3={d1,d2,d3,d4,d5}
 c4={d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6}
```

where b1 and b2 are subsets of b3 and b3 itself is a subset of b5, b4 is another subset of b5. c1 is a subset of c2 and c2 itself is a subset of c3 and c3 itself is a subset of c4. Assume that all of the elements in all sets are string (a1...a12 are string and d1..d6 are also string). Is it possible to do hierarchical clustering in Python using Sklearn? if not, only the names of the last subsets would be fine, b1,b2,b4 and c1 in here.

Answer (score 0):

As I know sklearn.cluster uses non-string format.

I have a idea - you use [pd.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to convert your data to integer format. But, as you have collection of set you need to check how correct your new dataset. After this you can use any clusterization, for instance [BIRCH](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.Birch.html)